# "Type&" vs "Type*" in C++ function definitions

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I understand the pointer concept (`int*`), but I cannot understand `int&` because they give the same result. What does `int &data` exactly mean?

```
void add1(int *data){
  (*data)++;
}

void add2(int &data){
  data++;
}

int main()
{
  int i=0;

  add1(&i);
  printf ("value i = %d\n",i) // show 1

  add2(i);
  printf ("value i = %d\n",i); // show 2

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't using a C++ compiler?

Comment: `&` means a reference to.

Comment: @DanielA.White references are a feature in C++, not C

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function signature:

```
void add2(int &data)
```

is the pass-by-reference facility in C++. It's a way to allow the function to *change* the value passed in and have that change reflected back to the caller. In C, upon which C++ was originally based, all paramaters are pass-by-value, meaning the functions get a *local* copy which, if changed, does *not* affect the original value passed in.

> As an aside, pass by reference is probably the one facility I'd *most* like to see added to C (not full-blown C++ references, just in the function calls) since I'm pretty certain 42% of all C questions here on SO have to do with pointers :-)

The way to do pass-by-reference in C and C++ can be seen in the lines below. The first is the right way to do it in C++, and the second is the "pointer gymnastics" poor C developers have to go through to get the same effect:

```
void FortyTwo(int &x) { x = 42; }     // Call with FortyTwo(variable);
void FortyTwo(int *pX) { *pX = 42; }  // Call with FortyTwo(&variable);
```

In the latter, the *pointer* is passed by value but you can use that pointer to get at (and change) the data it points to. In C++, you should, as much as possible, avoid passing the pointers to values you want to change since that's one of the reasons references were added to C++ in the first place. It also makes your code easier to understand if you don't have to pepper it with pointer dereferences.